# Coded UI. How can I change TimeOut in Find() method

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm new in automation testing. I need help.

I have example

```
updateWindow = new WpfWindow();

updateWindow.SearchProperties[WpfWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = updateWindowName;

updateWindow.Find
```

How can I change TimeOut for **Find()** method?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the timeout by setting the [SearchTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.playbacksettings.searchtimeout.aspx) option in the global [PlaybackSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.playbacksettings.aspx) object.

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 1000;
updateWindow.Find();
```

You could also wrap it in a function.

```
public void FindTimeout(UITestControl control, int time)
{
    int old_timeout = Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout;
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = time;
    control.Find();
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = old_timeout;
}
```